# Store Command Line arguments in a character array on Linux

Tags: c, linux, arguments

i am new on Linux. I want to ask that how to store a command line argument in a character array. I am using the following code from an hour but I am unable to solve this problem(Segmentation fault Core Dumped).
Here is the code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[]) {
    char * MyIp[15];
    int j = 0;
    while(argv[1][j] != '\0') {
        MyIp[j] = argv[1][j++];
    }
    printf("IP : %s\n", *MyIp);
    return 0;
}
```

and command line argument

```
./code.o "127.0.0.1"
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Comment: Why have you tagged it "java"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with the small code you shown. First of all you declare `MyIp` to be an array of pointers to `char`, i.e. an array of strings. You assign to it from `argv[1][j++]` which is a *single character*, and when printing you print `*MyIp` as a string (which it is declared as) but the problem here is that the pointer you print (`MyIp[0]`) is initialized by a character and it's not a very valid pointer.

What you seem to want is to copy the single string `argv[1]`, in which case there are *much* simpler methods, like e.g. [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) which were made to copy strings with specific lengths:

```
char MyIp[15];
if (argc > 1)
{
    strncpy(MyIp¸ argv[1], 14);
    MyIp[14] = '\0';  // If `argv[1]` is too long, terminate manually
}
else
    strcpy(MyIp, "Unknown");

printf("IP : %s\n", MyIp);
```